# Compute all products for all numbers in a python list

Tags: python

Let's say that I have this list :

```
[2,3,5,7]
```

I want to output all combinations of multiplication :

```
[6,10,14,15,21,35,30,42,105,210]
```

Is there a one liner in python for that?

Comment: What have you actually *tried* so far?

Comment: I've googled a lot trying to find something, but it looks like map, reduce, etc. might not help right away

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Where's your *code*? Have you looked into `itertools`?

Comment: `sorted({a * b for (a, b) in combinations(values, 2)})`

Comment: @PeterWood - Nope - it includes other combinations (e.g. `210` is `2*3*5*7`).

Comment: @jonrsharpe I guess I could do combinations 2 to len of the list?

Comment: By the way, isn't this called the Cartesian expansion or something using the multiplication operator?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that you forgot the 70 in your output...

With `numpy.prod` and `itertools.combinations`:

```
>>> from numpy import prod
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> lst = [2,3,5,7]
>>> [prod(x) for i in range(2, len(lst)+1) for x in combinations(lst, i)]
[6, 10, 14, 15, 21, 35, 30, 42, 70, 105, 210]
```

Comment: I don't use the numpy package so I used : `reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, numbers)`

Comment: Dont need import `numpy` for this task

Comment: @Argman yes, using reduce instead of `numpy.prod` is possible, but I argue that it is harder to read. If you can't use numpy, reduce (or writing your own prod function) are valid fallback solutions.

Comment: @timgeb I think `reduce` is not hard-read , however maybe you right

Comment: This uses a special case of the `powerset` [recipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes)

Comment: @MaximeRoussin-Bélanger You don't actually need the lambda function in your `reduce` expression since it already exists: `reduce(int.__mul__, numbers)` but, of course, you have to be sure you are using integers here.

Answer (score 2):

Itertools is the good way. As an alternative solution, a pure numpy one (all products of 0,1,...,n terms) :

```
from numpy import *
a,n=array(l),len(l)
where(bitwise_and.outer(arange(2**n),2**arange(n))>0,a,1).prod(1)
#array([  1,   2,   3,   6,   5,  10,  15,  30,   7,  14,  21,  42,  35, 70, 105, 210])
```

up to 40x faster on big lists.

Some explanation:

`bitwise_and.outer(arange(2**n),2**arange(n))` is

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 4, 0],
       [1, 0, 4, 0],
       [0, 2, 4, 0],
       [1, 2, 4, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 8],
       [1, 0, 0, 8],
       [0, 2, 0, 8],
       [1, 2, 0, 8],
       [0, 0, 4, 8],
       [1, 0, 4, 8],
       [0, 2, 4, 8],
       [1, 2, 4, 8]], dtype=int32)
```

`where(bitwise_and.outer(arange(2**n),2**arange(n))>0,a,1)` is

```
array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 3, 1, 1],
       [2, 3, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 5, 1],
       [2, 1, 5, 1],
       [1, 3, 5, 1],
       [2, 3, 5, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 7],
       [2, 1, 1, 7],
       [1, 3, 1, 7],
       [2, 3, 1, 7],
       [1, 1, 5, 7],
       [2, 1, 5, 7],
       [1, 3, 5, 7],
       [2, 3, 5, 7]])
```

Then the `prod` by line.

Comment: Nice, but could you add some explanation what's going on? How to prevent the values 1,2,3,5,7 being in the result?

Comment: edited. The exact solution in two lines : `y=bitwise_and.outer(arange(2**n),2**arange(n))>0; res= where(y,a,1).prod(1)[y.sum(1)>1]` . But restricting at 2 or more operands is mathematically a ugly problem for me (and for computers  too ...)

Answer (score 0):

A tricky one-liner using no extra tools...

Assuming your initial list is in the variable `l`:

```
[ list(l[k] for k in range(len(l))
    if (2**k) & (n+(n+n.bit_length()).bit_length()))
    for n in range(1,2**len(l)-len(l)) ]
```

returns the combinations you need (just wrap the initial list with some `reduce` for performing the multiplication itself but the tricky part is there). The "gem" is `n+(n+n.bit_length()).bit_length()` which maps positive integers to the sequence of integers containing at least *two* bits sets (in their binary expansion), which is used for selecting members of the initial list by being sure that at least *two* of them are taken each time. You can learn more about this formula at http://oeis.org/A057716 (I merely adapted to Python syntax the first expression in the "Formula" part of the previous link).

Thus, the whole answer will be:

```
[ reduce(int.__mul__,
    (l[k] for k in range(len(l))
        if (2**k) & (n+(n+n.bit_length()).bit_length())))
        for n in range(1,2**len(l)-len(l)) ]
```

(You need to import `reduce` if you are using Python 3.)